# Need Help Unit Testing with Rails 5 for Update Action Always Fail on assert_equals

Tags: ruby, unit-testing, ruby-on-rails-5

i want to test an update action in my rails project. The function is running well, but when i try to unit-test it's always fail. Can you help this?

i'm new with ruby and unit-testing. i've tried with any documentation it still not solve this test.

this is my `Content Controller` function that i want to test, i use clearance for auth

```
before_action :require_login
def update
   @content = Content.find(params[:id])
   if @content.update(content_params)
      flash[:notice] = 'success'
      redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
   else
      flash[:notice] = 'fail'
      redirect_back fallback_location: root_path
   end
end
```

this is my `Content Fixture`

```
one: 
  id: '1'
  about: 'about content'
  privacy: 'privacy content'
  terms: 'terms content'
```

this is my `test_helper`

```
ENV['RAILS_ENV'] ||= 'test'
require_relative '../config/environment'
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'clearance/test_unit'

class ActiveSupport::TestCase
  fixtures :all
end

class ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
  def sign_in_as_user
    user = User.create!(email: "example@example.com", password: "letmein")
    post session_url, params: {
      session: {
        email: user.email,
        password: user.password
      }
    }
  end
end
```

And this is my test code

```
test "should update content" do
    sign_in_as_user
    content = contents(:one)
    put content_url(content), params: { about: { syarat: "updated about", privacy: "updated privacy", terms: "updated terms" } }
    content.reload
    assert_equal "updated about", content.about
    assert_equal "updated privacy", content.privacy
    assert_equal "updated terms", content.terms
  end
```

Then i run the test `rake test`, this is the result

```
Failure:
ContentControllerTest#test_should_update_content [/Users/abc/Documents/PROJECT/Apps/test-app/test/controllers/content_controller_test.rb:20]:
--- expected
+++ actual
@@ -1 +1 @@
-"updated about"
+"about content"
```

Comment: What eq `flash[:notice]` after your `put` in test case?

Comment: @QNester it must be 'success'

Comment: I understood what it must, but I want to know what in fact :) Not enough details to resolve your problem. You should use debugger to understand action behave in test case. Maybe your test case failed coz of auth?

Comment: @QNester you're right, thank you, i use byebug then i found an error at sign_in_as_user

Comment: @QNester however, each function should use `sign_in_as_user`, i've tried in another test with remove `sign_in_as_user` then it will return fail too